# Throwing multiple exceptions from one method

Tags: java, exception, throw

How do you throw more than one exception at once from one method? Example:

```
public void doA() throws Exception1, Exception2{
    throw new Exception1("test1");
    throw new Exception2("test2");
}
```

How to make something like this work?

Edit : one condition throws both Exception1 and Exception2. Possible?
This is just a demo file to test throwing exceptions.

Comment: What is it supposed to achieve ?

Answer (score 9):

You should check if something is not right in the method to throw the `Exception`. Here's a sample:

```
public void doA() throws Exception1, Exception2 {
    if (<some unexpected condition>) {
        throw new Exception1("test1");
    }
    if (<another unexpected condition>) {
        throw new Exception2("test2");
    }
    //rest of the implementation...
}
```

If you mean how to throw several exceptions at the same time, that's not possible since throwing a exception will break the execution of the method (similar to a `return`). You can only throw one `Exception` at a time.

Comment: That's not at all what the OP asked, just random advice.

Comment: @Warlord from OP's question: *one condition throws both Exception1 and Exception2. Possible?*.

Answer (score 1):

You can throw only one exception at a time. You cannot do what you are asking for. Instead, think about using custom exceptions in your code, and use them, depending on the situation (I am not sure about the reason why you need to throw two exceptions) :

```
class CustomException extends Exception
{
    //Parameterless Constructor
    public CustomException() {}

    //Constructor that accepts a message
    public CustomException(String message)
    {
     super(message);
    }
}
```

and then throw it when you need to:

```
public void doA() throws Exception1, Exception2{
   throw new CustomException("test1, test2");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question was how can you throw more than one exception from a method **at the same time** then the answer is you just can't. After the first exception is thrown the control exits this method and the Exception is rolling in it's parent method. If there is nothing which catches it then it goes to it's parent method and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to throw more than one exception at-once.

However, depending on the requirement, you can throw a nested exception, when you need to pass contextually the (sic) second exception:

```
throw new Exception("My exception", new Exception("The cause of My Exception"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Throwing exception is an one-way transfer of control to another line of code (like jump in assembly language). That means after the throwing statement the program should be executing necessarily another line of code outside that scope (at first calling code in stack which handle that exception).