# Java method multiple throw exception

Tags: java, exception

Is there any way I can throw multiple exceptions in the method(method called "test")?

```
package com.company;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

static Exception exception = new FileNotFoundException();
static Exception exception2 = new IOException();
static Exception exception3 = new ArithmeticException();
static Exception exception4 = new NumberFormatException();


public static void test() throws Exception {
   throw exception;
   //how can I throw exception2, exception3 and exception4 all at the same time?

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    test();
}
```

}`

Comment: No, one exception can be thrown, an exception can have a nested exception within but a method can only throw **one** exception.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Throwing multiple exceptions from one method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22229171/throwing-multiple-exceptions-from-one-method)

Comment: You could use the `addSuppressed()` to add your exceptions to a single "root" exception

Comment: Additionally I suggest you to read this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489655/throwing-always-the-same-exception-instance-in-java, essentially: *Always* create a new instance of an exception, don't reuse them